# How to check a string for a list of words in a file using R

Tags: r, dplyr, nlp

data1 in strings.xlsx has text as rows. Column name is 'heading'
"Quick fox ran over the desk"
"Quick red fox jumped over the dog"
"Red fox crossed the road"
"Quick red dog crossed the ROAD"

data2 in keywords.xlsx has keywords:
fox
Jump
DOG
cross
road

I want to check all data2 keywords in data1
The csv output file should have 'heading' column from data1
And all keywords in data2 should become columns with 1s and 0s for match/no match

I have tried the following

```
library(readxl)
library(openxlsx)
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
data1 = read_excel("strings.xlsx")
data1$heading = sapply(data1$heading, tolower) #need the same for keyword.xlsx
v1 <- readxl::read_excel('keywords.xlsx') %>% pull(1)
for(v in v1){
data1 <- data1 %>%
mutate(!! v := as.integer(heading %like% v))
}
```

Comment: Can you show the output of 'v1'

Comment: I am assuming that the colum name of 'data1' is `1stColumn`(based on your code) and in the loop you are using `words` as column name? shouldn't that be `mutate(!! v := as.integer(`1stColumn` %like v))` please wrap the `1stColumn` in backquotes as it is starting with a number

Comment: Output of v1 [1] "jump" "dog" "cross" "road"

Comment: It seems to be the issue of column name in the `mutate` step  you are using 'words' (not clear whether it is the column name or 1stColumn (your examples doesn't show the column name)

Comment: Correct data1 has data in 1stColumn. Yes..my bad. replacing words with 1stColumn

Comment: Make sure that it is wrapped in backquotes as it is a special column name starting with number

Comment: Thanks a ton and for your patience. Renamed the 1stColumn to heading to make it simple

Comment: Yea..It works..I was using the wrong column name :). One last thing: I am using 'tolower' to convert data1 to lower...how do I add it to data2 as well

Comment: you meant `as.integer(tolower(heading) %like% v)`

Comment: I am already taking care of heading with data1$heading = sapply(data1$heading, tolower). I need to do the same for data2 which has keywords under 'words' column

Comment: You mean the `v1`  from `v1 <- readxl::read_excel('keywords.xlsx') %>% pull(1)`   You are just mixing names so it is confusing.  Just do `v1 <- tolower(v1)`

Comment: `tolower` is vectorized so you don't need `sapply(data1$heading, tolower)` instead it can be `tolower(data1$heading)`

Comment: Sorry my bad. But I want to do v1 <- tolower(v1) before pull(1) happens

Comment: you can do `v1 <- readxl::read_excel('keywords.xlsx')  %>% mutate(words = tolower(words)) %>% pull(1)` (assuming the column name is 'words')

Comment: Thank you @akrun I extended the code to read multiple files for keywords and give output in the same file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `map`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
v1 <- c('vitamin', 'amino')
map_dfc(v1, ~ 
        as.integer(data[['columnname']] %like% .x)) %>%
    set_names(v1) %>%
    bind_cols(data1, .)
```

---

Or with a `for` loop

```
v1 <- c('vitamin', 'amino')
for(v in v1){
       data1 <- data1 %>%
                   mutate(!! v := as.integer(columnname %like% v))
 }
```

---

If the vector of words are getting read from an excel file (assuming it is the first column)

```
v1 <- readxl::read_excel('file.xlsx') %>%
                  pull(1)
```

Comment: the list of words is in an excel file. How do I call that excel file to check the list of words?

Comment: Yes ok. thanks. I am going to try the 'for loop' by replacing c('vitamin', 'amino') with excel file which has keywords

Comment: Error: The LHS of `:=` must be a string or a symbol 
data1 = read_excel("strings.xlsx")
data2 = read_excel("keywords.xlsx")
for(v in data2){
  data3 <- data2 %>%
    mutate(!! v := as.integer(words %like% v))
}

Comment: data1 in strings.xlsx has text as rows in 1st column
"Quick fox ran over the desk"
"Quick red fox jumped over the dog"
"Quick red dog crossed the ROAD"

data2 in keywords.xlsx has keywords:
fox
Jump
DOG
cross
road

    library(readxl)
    library(openxlsx)
    library(tidyverse)
    library(data.table)
    data1 = read_excel("strings.xlsx")
    data1$1stColumn = sapply(data1$1stColumn, tolower) #need the same for keyword.xlsx
    v1 <- readxl::read_excel('keywords.xlsx') %>% pull(1)
    for(v in v1) { data1 <- data1 %>%
    mutate(!! v := as.integer(words %like% v))
}

Comment: thank you. Will review the same to get better at asking

Comment: Edited the question...I hope it is better now